# SSL Certificate host name mismatch in certbot even though both names have certificates

Tags: laravel, ssl, nginx, https, certbot

I'm stuck on how to fix this SSL error --

My SSL certs work fine on Chrome, but in Safari and Firefox I get an error that there is a host name mismatch if I go to www.domain.com instead of just domain.com

I've set up SSL Certificates using Certbot for my domain for both domain.com and www.domain.com

When I check on nginx to make sure that the certificates exist, I run `sudo certbot --nginx`, then select both of the domains when asked `Which names would you like to activate https for?`, and for both domain.com and www.domain.com, I get the result `"You have an existing certificate that has exactly the same domains or certificate name you requested and isn't close to expiry"` and asks if I'd like to attempt to reinstall or renew and replace the cert.

I'm not sure what other steps I can take, as last time I installed certbot I simply followed the instructions, did the above for both www and non-www addresses, and it simply worked at both www and non-www!

Does anyone have any suggestions what to do next?

**TLDR:**

domain.com: works fine in firefox/safari, nginx says cert exists

www.domain.com: host name mismatch in firefox/safari, nginx says cert exists

why?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After messing with it for a while, and trying @xyz's ssl checker I figured out the following things:

both certs were valid

When I re-installed the certs using certbot, the most recent cert would start working and the previous one would stop working

Turned out that i needed to add the other url as a subdomain to the existing cert and that fixed it!

I used:

`sudo certbot -d domain.com -d www.domain.com`

and that did the trick

Answer (score 1):

You can check both domains from an external service, e.g. here:

https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html

It will tell you if the certificate is correctly installed on both.

You should also open a new tab in Chrome, open developer tools, record network requests, then goto www.domain.com and see what redirects Chrome makes and what URL's it actually makes requests to. Maybe it has some automatic URL changing based on previously successfully resolved URL's.

Comment: So this told me both certs were valid but I figured out the issue, will post as answer